# Shifting description by a user defined amount

Tags: lists

Have managed to start the label of list at the beginning of the text area as an equivalent to

I would like to have the following output

```
LABEL.1999-DEF8
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
```

Where "LABELxxx" starts at the left margin (beginning at location of no indentation).  Whilst the following paragraph starting with `DESC.Deligne` (constituting the body of the environment) being shifted to the right by a user defined dimension.

But I cannot make the description supplied in the body of the environment that starts on the next line to have a horizontal shift defined by the value of the first argument `#1` to `Spar`.

Adding `#1` to `\leftmargin` has not proved to shift any text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment {Spar} { O{0.3cm} m }
  {
    \list {}
      {
        \setlength {\leftmargin} {\dimexpr\leftmargin+#1\relax}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
        %% \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}
        \renewcommand* \makelabel [1]
          { \rlap { \parbox[b] {\linewidth} 
                      { 
                        %%\hspace*{\labelsep}
                        \normalfont\bfseries ##1
                        \endgraf\mbox{}
                      }
                  }
          %% \hspace{\leftmargin}
      }}
  \item[{[#2]}]
  }
    { \endlist }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\geometry { b5paper, 
  left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm,
  includehead, includefoot }

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Spar}{LABEL.1999-DEF8}
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; "Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians."  Vol. 1-2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about labelsep?

Comment: Where could I introduce `\labelsep` ?  Have tried `\setlength {\labelsep} {#1}` before `\renewcommand*`, but this shifts the label to the left, rather than indent the entire description to the right.

Comment: See my answer, please! You were almost there.

Comment: just  set leftmargin as shown previously, most simply vial leftmargin= in enumitem

Comment: A new user name? What happened to all the other ones?

Comment: Have changed `leftmargin` to add `#1`.  Still the item description does not shift according to different values of `#1`.

Comment: How is this setmargin got to be set up, that is, what would be the appropriate calculation for it ?  Using different values for `#1` dous not result in a different shift in the environment body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using a one-item list? You can, with `enumitem`, but there's no reason to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Spar}{ O{0.3cm} m }{%
  \itemize[
    wide,
    leftmargin=\dimeval{\leftmargini+#1},
    nosep,
    itemindent=-\leftmargin,
    labelsep=0pt,
    labelwidth=0pt,
    align=left,
    listparindent=0pt,
  ]
  \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
    \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\normalfont\bfseries [##1]}
  }%
  \item[#2]\mbox{}\par\nopagebreak
}
{\enditemize}

\geometry{
  b5paper, 
  left=8mm,
  right=8mm,
  top=8mm,
  bottom=8mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Spar}{LABEL.1999-DEF8}
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{Spar}[3cm]{LABEL.1999-DEF8}
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
\end{Spar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd simply use a command, rather than an environment and `\leftskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Spar}{O{0.3cm}m+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargini}% standard for first level lists
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{#1}%
  % the label
  \hspace*{-\leftskip}\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\normalfont\bfseries [#2]}\par
  \nopagebreak\ignorespaces #3\par
  \endgroup
}

\geometry{
  b5paper, 
  left=8mm,
  right=8mm,
  top=8mm,
  bottom=8mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\Spar{LABEL.1999-DEF8}{
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\Spar[3cm]{LABEL.1999-DEF8}{
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
}

\end{document}
```

If the optional argument should define the amount of shifting, the second code should become

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Spar}{O{0.3cm}mm}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{#1}
  % the label
  \hspace*{-\leftskip}\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\normalfont\bfseries [#2]}\par
  \nopagebreak\ignorespaces #3\par
  \endgroup
}

\geometry{
  b5paper, 
  left=8mm,
  right=8mm,
  top=8mm,
  bottom=8mm,
  includehead,
  includefoot
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\Spar{LABEL.1999-DEF8}{
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\Spar[0pt]{LABEL.1999-DEF8}{
  DESC.Deligne Pierre, Etingof Pavel, et al., 1999; ``Quantum Fields and
  Strings: A Course for Mathematicians.''  Vol. 1--2. With Freed Daniel
  S., Jeffrey Lisa C., Kazhdan David, Morgan John W., Morrison David R.,
  Witten Edward.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `enumitem` based code, change

```
leftmargin=\dimeval{\leftmargini+#1},
```

into

```
leftmargin=#1,
```

Comment: Some people keep insisting to use `enumitem`.  I have stressed that there is no reason to, just as you have pointed out.  But the patronising attitude by many seems endemic.

Comment: @Ragonese Managing lists with `enumitem` is far simpler than with `\list`. I *do* recommend it, but not for this application, where even `\list` is not the best tool.

Comment: I agree.  Have used `0cm` for the shift but the result does not align with the `LABEL` part.

Comment: @Ragonese Sorry, but from your code I deduced that you wanted to *add* the amount optionally specified to the standard `\leftmargin`. If `0.3cm` (or what the user asks for) should be the precise amount of shifting, just remove the references to `\leftmargini`.

Comment: Yes, I would like that the user defined shift dimension is the actual shift relative to the start of the label.

Comment: Why do you use `\itemize[` to then close with `\endlist` ?

Comment: @Ragonese Because I forgot to change.

Comment: Am grateful for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the macro can produce the shape you need. In your case `labelwidth`, `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` must be set to the same value. If you only want to increment, use a default length to start with and the add or decrement with a `\numexpr`. Always work with a figure for lists.

`\NewDocumentEnvironment {Spar} { O{30pt} m } {% \list {} { \setlength{\topsep}{0pt} \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \setlength{\labelwidth}{#1} \setlength\labelsep{0pt} \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt} \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1} \setlength{\rightmargin}{#1} \listparindent=\parindent \renewcommand* \makelabel [1] {\rlap{ \parbox[b] {\linewidth}  {  %%\hspace*{\labelsep} \normalfont\bfseries ##1 \endgraf\mbox{} } } }} \item[#2] } { \endlist }`

Comment: It is not the label that I want to shift but the environment body.  Shifted to the right by a user specified amount.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted, try calling it with different values and it will adjust the margins. As I mention in the post, if you only want the increment you need to use numexpr insteadof #1 only.

Comment: Yes, I did use your code.  However I got the label shifting to the left rather than the body shifting to the right.